# Cannot save token from axios response (in discord bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js, response

```
var TOKEN = "";

async function getToken() {
  axios
    .post(url, data)
    .then((response) => {
      TOKEN = response.data.token;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("failed to login");
    });
}
```

The code is supposed to get a token, that would be used for further requests something like that:

```
await getToken();
await getSomethingUsingToken();
```

But token is not saved to variable.
I also tried:

```
async function getToken() {
  let token;
  axios
    .post(url, data)
    .then((response) => {
      token = response.data.token;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("failed to login");
    });
  return token;
}
```

Code is called from a discord bot.

Comment: Resolved. Had to add await before axios.post. (Thank you, Ezio for answer it helped)

Answer (score 2):

It's not being saved  because of the asynchronous nature of the axios request. In the second example, you're returning the token before the promise from axios has resolved, so it returns undefined.

To fix this, you can make use of the async/await pattern. so modify the getToken function like this:

```
var TOKEN = "";

async function getToken() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, data);
    TOKEN = response.data.token;
    return TOKEN;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("failed to login");
    throw error;
  }
}
```

With this change, when you use await getToken(), JavaScript will wait for the Axios request to complete and then proceed to the next line, ensuring that the TOKEN value is updated before moving on to getSomethingUsingToken.

When you call the function, you can do:

```
try {
  await getToken();
  await getSomethingUsingToken();
} catch (error) {
  console.log('There was an error.');
}
```

Lastly await need async so make sure the event handler is async if this is inside an event handler in discord